# Ruby on Rails, save! returns true but database row is unchanged (only in production; works fine in development)

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

(Using jruby-1.6.8, Rails 2.3.14)

I have a Ruby object, `experiment`, I'm trying to use to update an existing row in a mysql database with `.save!`, and even though `save!` and `valid?` both return `true` on the object, the db row is unchanged after doing:

```
>> result = experiment.save!
=> true
```

Has anybody ever run into this problem? Also, it works fine in development; production is where the problem is occurring. How can that break it? There is no error to indicate that the row was not updated by `save!`. The only thing that changes is that the row's `updated_at` column gets a later time written to it.

I added code later on that grabs the object's attributes individually and does an sql `UPDATE` with those. This works, but I want to get to the root of the `save!` problem:

```
sql = "UPDATE experiment SET attr1 = #{experiment.attr1}, attr2 = #{experiment.attr2} WHERE experimentID = #{experiment.experimentID}"
Experiment.connection.execute(sql)
```

Here is what the experiment object looks like:

```
>> puts "#{experiment.inspect}"
=> #<Experiment experimentID: 177, attr1: 13, attr2: 13, attr3: nil ... >
```

`SELECT` output of the database row before doing `save!`:

```
>> test_sql = "SELECT * FROM experiment WHERE experimentID = #{experiment.experimentID}"
>> sql_hash = Experiment.connection.execute(test_sql)[0]
>> puts "before save: SQL_TEXT: #{sql_hash.inspect}"
=> before save: SQL_TEXT: {"experimentID"=>177, "attr1"=>0, "attr2"=>0, "attr3"=>"", ... }
```

Then, `experiment.save!` should update attr1 and attr2 to 13. However, they are still 0.

Here's some of the applicable class declaration:

```
class Experiment < ActiveRecord::Base
  set_table_name :experiment
  set_primary_key :experimentID
  validates_presence_of :attr1, :attr2
  ...
end
```

EDIT: Per commenter's suggestion, I tried setting production logger level to debug and looking at the actual SQL being queried by `experiment.save!`:

```
Experiment Update (0.0ms)   UPDATE `experiment` SET `updated_at` = '2013-09-02 19:56:11' WHERE `experimentID` = 178
```

Why would `save!` choose to *not* update any of the attributes???

Please let me know if there are any other details I can provide.

Comment: Are you actually setting those attributes? Where's the code?

Comment: Have you tried enabling debug log level in production and looking at actual queries that are executed?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev, the code to set the attributes is `experiment.save!`, like I showed above. That should update the DB with all of the `experiment` object's attributes, correct?

I will enable the debug log level and see what I get, thanks for that suggestion.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev: Edited to show that the `save!` sql query contains no attributes from `experiment` object. Why would it do that?

Comment: How are you updating the object before you call save on it?

Comment: @FrederickCheung, There are many updates to the object by commands like `experiment.attr1 = 55` and it gets passed to different methods and updated within. It also gets converted to a java object and modified further, beforehand. That seems to be where the offending update to the DB row occurs that wipes out the row's data. I'm looking into that now.

Answer (score 2):

Active Record tracks which columns have changed and only saves these to the database. This change tracking is not all knowing, for example

```
user.name.gsub!(...)
```

wouldn't be detected as a change prior to rails 4.2.

There are 2 ways around this. One is never to change any Active Record object attribute in place. If you can't do this then you must tell Active Record what you have done, for example

```
user.name.gsub!(...)
user.name_will_change!
```

lets Active Record know that the name attribute has changed

Comment: So, a change to a column done like this: `user.name = 'John Smith'` _would be_ detected by ActiveRecord?